# Noughts and Crosses winner declaration in a game of variable square board size

Tags: php, algorithm, tic-tac-toe

I have made a tic tac toe for two players and written down some functions to do the decision making about who is the winner. I have gone through some cases while testing but need advice to see if I am in the right track and also if all the winning positions are being taken care of.
*I would like to know even if this can be simplified.*

**Here:**
`$state = ["&#10008;","-","-","-","-","&#10008;","-","-","-","-","&#10008;","-","-","-","-‌​","&#10008;"]`

The function is for grids starting from ***3X3*** to ***7X7***.

**PHP**

```
function whoIsWinning($state)
{
    $n = sqrt(count($state));
    $rows = $this->isWin($state, $this->genPaths($n, 0,     1,      $n, $n));
    $cols = $this->isWin($state, $this->genPaths($n, 0,     $n,     1,  $n));
    $diUp = $this->isWin($state, $this->genPaths(1, $n-1,  $n-1,   0,  $n));
    $diDn = $this->isWin($state, $this->genPaths(1,  0,     $n+1,   0,  $n));

    if ($rows !== '-') return $rows;
    if ($cols !== '-') return $cols;
    if ($diUp !== '-') return $diUp;
    return $diDn;
}

/**
 * Function to generate the paths to win
 * @param $count
 * @param $start
 * @param $incrementA
 * @param $incrementB
 * @param $lengthToWin
 * @return array
 */
function genPaths($count, $start, $incrementA, $incrementB, $lengthToWin)
{
    $paths = [];
    if($lengthToWin > 3) {
        $lengthToWin = $lengthToWin - 1;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $path = [];
        for($j = 0; $j < $lengthToWin; $j++) {
            array_push($path, $start + $i * $incrementB + $j * $incrementA);
        }
        array_push($paths, $path);
    }
    return $paths;
}

/**
 * @param $state
 * @param $paths
 * @return string
 */
function isWin($state, $paths)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($paths); $i++) {
        $currentPathResult = $this->isPathWin($state, $paths[$i]);
        if ($currentPathResult != '-')
            return $currentPathResult;
    }
    return '-';
}

/**
 * @param $state
 * @param $path
 * @return string
 */
function isPathWin($state, $path)
{
    $first = $state[$path[0]];
    for ($j = 1; $j < count($path); $j++) {
        $compareToFirst = $state[$path[$j]];
        if ($compareToFirst != $first)
            return '-';
    }
    return $first;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain `$state`? Also it looks like there is stray `}` at end of this code. What is `whoIsWinning()` intended to do?

Comment: `$state` is the board state with moves made by players. `whoIsWinning()` is intended to find the winner.

Answer (score 2):

### About the logic of assessing victory:

After each player's turn there can only be one winner, so no matter how you want to write the functional parts it would be best practice to write a `return` as soon as a victor is found so that you don't do any surplus processing.

### The sample `$state` data:

- You have provided a 4x4 grid, with only one player's marks on it -- which is not realistic.
- You use `-` to identify unmarked cells -- I think blanks would be simpler/clearer.
- Player `X` has a diagonal sequence of 4 marks, even though victory (by your rules) is attained by 3 consecutive marks on a 4x4 grid.

### Some missing diagonal checks:

`$diUp` and `$diDn` have `$count` values of `1`.  This is accurate on 3x3 grids only.

Because `$lengthToWin` is `sqrt(count($state))-1`, all grids larger than 3x3 will have 4 winning diagonal sequences in each orientation (running down-to-the-right & down-to-the-left).

Considering a 4x4 grid, the winning sequences from upper-left to lower-right are:

- `[ 0 , 5 , 10 ]`
- `[ 1 , 6 , 11 ]`
- `[ 4 , 9 , 14 ]`
- `[ 5 , 10 , 15]`

The first and last sequences share the internal cells with indexes of `5` & `10`.

Here is a visual:

[image]

The same logic is applied to the sequences that start from the upper-right corner.

To crystallize... a 3x3 grid will have a total of 2 diagonal sequences, all other grids will have a total of 8 diagonal sequences.  The diagonal sequences obey a simple pattern, so you will have no trouble in generating the correct `path` for your function.

### My tinkerings:

I experimented a little with what I understood of your concepts and tried to employ array functions rather than for loops (though they are sometimes slower, I think they are better descriptors of action).  It is not a very tidy snippet (consider it a "napkin" draft), I didn't bother refining it because I am not 100% sure of your usage nor what is the best way to display the result.

```
function hasWon(array $vals,$mark){
    return empty(array_diff($vals,[$mark])); // retain opponent's mark and blanks, if empty = victory / true
}

function findFirstWinningSequence(array $state,$width,$mark){
    $lengthToWin=($width>3?$width-1:$width);
    // process horizontal and vertical sequences:
    $chunks=array_chunk($state,$width);
    foreach($chunks as $i=>$chunk){
        // full-length/width checks:
        if(hasWon(array_slice($chunk,0,$lengthToWin),$mark)){ // scan rows from left
            return "$mark wins via row ".++$i." from left";
        }
        $column=array_column($chunks,$i);  // cache column elements
        if(hasWon(array_slice($column,0,$lengthToWin),$mark)){ // scan cols from top
            return "$mark wins via column ".++$i." from top";
        }
        // length/width-1 checks
        if($width>3 && hasWon(array_slice($chunk,-$lengthToWin),$mark)){ // scan rows from right, if needed
            return "$mark wins via row ".++$i." from right";
        } 
        if($width>3 && hasWon(array_slice($column,-$lengthToWin),$mark)){ // scan cols from bottom, if needed
            return "$mark wins via column ".++$i." from bottom";
        } 
    }
    // process UpperLeft-to-LowerRight diagonal sequences:
    $starts=[0];  // index of first element in set
    if($width>3){
        $starts+=[1,$width,$width+1];
    }
    $increment=$width+1;  // the increment between each cell in sequence
    foreach($starts as $start){
        $keys=array_fill_keys(range($start,$start+$increment*($lengthToWin-1),$increment),null);
        // if $start=0 & $width=4, $keys=array_fill_keys(range(0,0+5*(3-1)=10,5),null); producing: [0=>null,5=>null,10=>null]
        if(hasWon(array_intersect_key($state,$keys),$mark)){
            return "$mark wins via diagonal from ".++$start." running down and to the right";
        }
    }
    // process UpperRight-to-LowerLeft diagonal sequences:
    $starts=[$width-1];  // index of first element in set
    if($width>3){
        $starts+=[$width-2,2*($width-1),2*($width-1)+1];
    }
    $increment=$width-1;  // the increment between each cell in sequence
    foreach($starts as $start){
        $keys=array_fill_keys(range($start,$start+$increment*($lengthToWin-1),$increment),null);
        // if $start=3 & $width=5, $keys=array_fill_keys(range(4,3+4*(3)=15,4),null); producing: [3=>null,7=>null,11=>null,15=>null]
        if(hasWon(array_intersect_key($state,$keys),$mark)){
            return "$mark wins via diagonal from ".++$start." running down and to the left";
        }
    }
}
$state=['X','','','','','X','','','','','X','','','','O','O'];
$width=sqrt(sizeof($state));
$mark='X';
echo findFirstWinningSequence($state,$width,$mark);
```

To conclude, your coding structure seems suitably segmented/clean.  It only requires the logical tunes ups that I mentioned before my snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The game has already been created, you can take a look at the repo here: https://github.com/whimsicaldreamer/XandO. Please feel free to PR if you find a bug. You can also try the demo http://xando.pe.hu/ to understand the usage. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your function `whoIsWinning($state)`, you call `$this->isWin(...)` four times, and in each one, the last parameter is $n, which is referenced as `$lengthToWin`. I'd try to find a way to eliminate that parameter by calculating it at the start of the `isWin` function.

In your `genPaths` function, you decrease `$lengthToWin` by one, which is misleading, because the $lengthToWin is not actually changing, you're just trying to deal with 0-based arrays. I would remove that `if` statement and change your for loop to:

`for($j = 0; $j < $lengthToWin-1; $j++) # to deal with 0-based arrays`

I would use a more descriptive variable name than `$count`. This my be just personal preference, but I think it's good practice to adequately describe the variable, such as `$numberOfPaths`.

Same comment for `$i` and `$j`. It would be so much more readable if you said:

`for ($currentPath = 0; $currentPath < $numberOfPaths; $currentPath++)`

and

`for ($currentCell = 0; $currentCell < $lengthToWin; $currentCell++)`

I would also recommend creating two variables, again for clarity:

```
$currentRow = $i * incrementB;
$currentCol = $j * incrementA;
```

and then using those variables in your inner loop:

```
array_push ($path, $start + $currentRow + $currentCol);
```

I have to go to a client now, but I'll come back and make some more comments.

Comment: For the `lengthToWin` in `genPaths` I was deducting 1 from the actual length as I want the winning length for grids above 3x3 to be 1 less than the actual length of the grid. Ex: In case of 4X4, the winning length should be 3, for 5X5 it should be 4 and so on.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't realize that. That makes sense, then, but I would document that.

Comment: What would you document?

Comment: I'd write `$lengthToWin -= 1; # only need n-1 to win on a grid of n`